# Merge multiple sheets (dynamically) in a Google Sheets spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Spreadsheet with 3 sheets containing data from different countries (`Country1`, `Country2`, `Country3`) and a 4th sheet (`Summary`) that is supposed to append these together. The columns are the same in all sheets.

I know already that I can combine them like this:

```
=QUERY({Country1!A2:G;Country2!A2:G;Country3!A2:G}; "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")
```

However, I need a way to combine an *arbitrary* amount of sheets together, without modifying the formula. So, if `Country4` gets added, this should be appended as well. How can I do that?

If it helps, I have a `Settings` sheet with a column that contains all the names of the countries (and therefore country sheet names). I have a script that dynamically generates new sheets if a country is added in the `Settings` sheet. If necessary, this script can also update the formula in the `Summary` sheet.

Comment: You wrote that you have a script that generates new sheets. As part of that script, why not then update your formula?

Comment: @Diego thanks. Yes, that's what I'm doing currently. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary").getRange('A1').setValue(summaryQuery);` But I was wondering if there is an easier/more effective method, without using scripts.

Comment: @otherguy I think this is not possible without using scripts if you do not know the number of sheets, what is the script you are using so far?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I do know the number and names of the sheets. Like I said, there is a `Settings` sheet with `Country1`, `Country2`, `Country3` in column `A`.

Comment: When I say `if you do not know the number of sheets` I really mean `for an arbitrary amount`. Sorry for my poor explanation. I believe this formula will need to be generated with a script for an arbitrary number of Sheets. I can provide this script for you, if you like?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Thanks. Currently I'm using the line above in the script, which does what I want. I was really just hoping for a simpler solution without scripts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can dynamically create the formula for this using an attached Script.*

#### Code:

```js
function generateFormula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var formula = "=QUERY({";
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var name = sheets[i].getName();
    if (name != "Settings" && name != "Summary") {
      formula = formula + name + "!A2:G;";
    }
  }
  formula = formula.slice(0, -1) + '}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL", 0)'
  ss.getSheetByName("Summary").getRange("A1").setFormula(formula);
}
```

This is just one possible way of doing this, though I do not believe it is possible to make it arbitrary without a script.

#### References:

- [Docs Editors Help - `QUERY` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [Google Apps Script - Method `Range.setFormula(formula)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String))